# golang sql package: return INOUT from postgres procedure

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to get the value from an INOUT parameter into the invoking go code.

I see some discussion [here](https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/issues/188) about oracle drivers supporting this. However, I am using PostgreSQL, and I want to access my INOUT parameter.

I have a postgres procedure that has an INOUT parameter like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo(INOUT my_variable text) LANGUAGE plpgsql ...
```

I am trying to get the variable by following the docs [here](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Out). I am writing something like this

```
import "database/sql"
db, _ := sql.Open(...some connection...)

tx, err := db.Begin()
defer tx.Rollback()

var myVariable string
if _, err := tx.Exec(`call foo(?);`, sql.Named("my_variable", sql.Named("my_variable", sql.Out{Dest: &myVariable, In: true}))
```

This returns

```
sql: converting argument with name "my_variable" type: unsupported type sql.Out, a struct
```

Has anyone been able to make this work with PostgreSQL
It seems like this should work, given that it is documented with the package. So, do the postgresql drivers not yet support this, or am I just missing some package import?

Comment: If you want to return something, use a function. Procedures aren't meant to return something.

Comment: this is mentioned in the Docs as well.

Not all drivers and databases support OUTPUT value parameters.https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=9545:9941#L362

Although you can use interface instead of string.

Comment: Ah thanks @arshpreet